# Por que no se muestra el mapa GOOGLE MAPS

Tags: javascript, google-maps

El problema es que cuando entro a la web no se ve nada, pero cuando hago `F5` sí aparece el mapa.

Este es el código del script que utiliza el Maps.

```
<script>
      var pxLat = -34.434063,
          pxLng = -58.510598;

      // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
      var map = google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

      function init() {
          // Basic options for a simple Google Map
          // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
          var mapOptions = {
              // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
              zoom: 5.5,

              disableDefaultUI: true,
              disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
              scrollwheel: false,
              // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3813426, 2.1596663),

              // How you would like to style the map. 
              // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
              styles: [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":40}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]}]
          };

          // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
          // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
          var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

          // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
          map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

          // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              icon: {
                fillColor: "#e6e6e6",
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 0,
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                scale: 8.8
              },
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3813426, 2.1596663),
              map: map,
              title: 'Barcelona: Estoy aquí (!)'
          });

          //- map.addListener('center_changed', function() {
          //-     window.setTimeout(function() {
          //-       map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
          //-     }, 500);
          //- });
      }

      function newLocation(level) {

         if(map.getZoom() > 2.5) { map.setZoom(2.5) } else { map.setZoom(2.5) }
      };
    </script>
```

He intentado con varias soluciones del `var map`, pero en cuanto modifico el mapa directamente no se carga más.

¿Alguna idea? Gracias!

Comment: La primera vez que abres la web y no se ve el mapa hay algún error en consola?

Comment: Si, estos errores.
www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-115945504-2:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
about.html:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at about.html:29
about.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) Vc

Comment: Me parece que el problema es lo que comenta Yakume, el mapa debe cargarse cuando se inicializa el mapa por esta razón se realiza en un callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que el error es que la librería de google no se carga cuando la variable map se intenta inicializar.

Según la [documentación de Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), se puede asignar un `callback` al importar el CDN:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=CALLBACK_FUNCTION"
    async defer></script>
```

deberías cambiar `YOUR_API_KEY` por tu key, `CALLBACK_FUNCTION` por `init`, que es la función a llamar cuando se cargue la librería, dejar map como `undefined` y asignarle un valor dentro de `init`.